# Unit Testing with backend process nested deep within code structure: Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a function which calls out to the operating system and obtains live data, so that every time the call is made the results will be different. The function which makes the call is nested behind five function calls, i.e. the call stack is five levels deep prior to making the OS call.

To test the top level function, one needs repeatable results. Two ways of doing the testing come to mind...
1.  Add an extra parameter to each of the five function calls, and pass in the "call out to the operating system", as a function. Then to unit test, the operating system function call is replaced by a function which returns static text
2.  Make the app aware of tests, and have the OS function return static text if it is running in the test environment. (I don't know how to do this)

I'd like to know; what is the recommended Elixir way of testing of a server process that is nested deep within the code structure?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mocks](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) to simulate the calls to the OS:

> For a simple example, if you wanted to test some code which calls `HTTPotion.get` to get a webpage but without actually fetching the webpage you could do something like this.
>
> ```
> defmodule MyTest do
>   use ExUnit.Case, async: false
>
>   import Mock
>
>   test_with_mock "test_name", HTTPotion,
>     [get: fn(_url) -> "<html></html>" end] do
>     HTTPotion.get("http://example.com")
>     assert called HTTPotion.get("http://example.com")
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> The `with_mock` creates a mock module. The keyword list provides a set of mock implementation for functions we want to provide in the mock (in this case just `get`). Inside `with_mock` we exercise the test code and we can check that the call was made as we expected using `called` and providing the example of the call we expected (the second argument `:_` has a special meaning of matching anything).

Comment: Mocks might be one way of implementing my "option 2." above.

Comment: @steve77 - the whole idea of mocking is that you can test the app _without_ it being aware of the test.